# Image automatically goes invisible after upload

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue once i upload my website online, an image doesn't show up, but only this one.
I got it in a

```
<div class="x">
    <img src="img/img.png">
</div>
```

without any CSS added to "x"

Now when my site is online, and when i look at the CSS applied to it i got:

`display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
  background-position: 1px 1px;`

But i didn't write this, why does this apply automatically ? Also the issue does not occure when i'm "offline" and see the website through my computer.
When i edit the CSS online through Chrome, the image still not shows up.
I don't understand this, hope someone could help me !

Comment: Could you provide a link to the site?

Comment: When you inspect the class via Chrome Developer Tools it will show you the CSS-file plus the line where this comes from.

Comment: The CSS is written in element.style { , no CSS file related.
Even the HTML changes from <img src=> to "<img src="img/img.png" width="0" height="0" style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 1px 1px;">"

Answer (score 0):

You could create an inline style to try and ovverride:

A link would be most helpful to see where that CSS is being pulled from

```
<img src="img/img.png" style="display:block !important; visibility:visible
!important; opacity:1 !important;">
```